# Lathe Bed Differential Wear Tool Offset Calculation

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

This is probably an odd one here,

I'm trying to calculate the linear offset that a tool needs to have to meet a circle of any radius r with an arbitrary offset y and arbitrary angle ϴ. The tool holder "height" from the bed surface is fixed and can be taken as a constant, but is also arbitrary and will vary lathe to lathe. I am trying to "map" this offset on my own, but would like to have a general formula to calculate the offset programmatically from measured values to incorporate into a LinuxCNC component so other users with this issue can measure and compensate their own machines.

I've linked an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCxkg.png) with a green circle showing the distance between the circle and "tool" I'm trying to calculate, note this distance should be along theta and not along the origin axis. All of the dimensions are exaggerated for effect, in reality the difference will likely be within a few thousandths of an inch. Note that I have assumed that as the bed wears the left edge remains in the same plane. This is the edge of the lathe carriage that is "guided," the other is free to move laterally.

I've racked my brain and just can't come up with anything to describe how this gap interacts with the variables. CAD has been no help, either. I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me out with this.

Comment: So, we assume the tool carriage "hinges" from the far rail, with wear $y$ on the near rail, causing a rotation of $\theta$ with $$\tan\theta = \frac{y}{L}$$ where $L$ is the distance between the near and far rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the lathe tool passes through the center of the axis, no compensation is necessary, since the coordinate system is just rotated around the axis by $\theta$.

---

Consider the following diagram, with differential wear $y$, causing the tool carriage to tilt/turn by angle $\theta$,
$$\tan\theta = \frac{y}{L} \tag{1}\label{G1}$$
[image: Lathe diagram]
The vertical error $v$ at the tool tip is
$$v = \frac{L - w_5}{L} y = \frac{w_1 + w_2 - w_5}{w_1 + w_2} y \tag{2a}\label{G2a}$$
and if the axis is centered between the rails ("pivot points" of the rails), then the tool height error $\epsilon$ (i.e., how much below the center of the axis the tool height is, when it is directly below the center of the axis), is
$$\epsilon = \frac{w_1}{L} y = \frac{w_1}{w_1 + w_2} y = \frac{y}{2} \quad \text{if} \quad w_1 = w_2 \tag{3a}\label{G3a}$$

---

Let's use $\beta$ for the "balance factor",
$$\beta = \frac{w_1}{w_1 + w_2} \tag{4}\label{G4}$$
If the axis is exactly midway between the rails, then $\beta = 0.5$.  If the axis is closer to the tool edge, $\beta \gt 0.5$; if the axis was right over the tool edge pivot point, then $\beta = 1$.  If the axis is closer to the other edge, $\beta \lt 0.5$; if the axis was right over the other edge pivot point, then $\beta = 0$.  As far as I know, $\beta = 0.5$ for most lathes.

Then, the tool height error $\epsilon$ is
$$\epsilon = \beta y \quad \iff \quad y = \frac{\epsilon}{\beta} \tag{3b}\label{G3b}$$
and the vertical error at the tool $v$ is
$$v = \left(\frac{L - w_5}{L}\right)\left(\frac{\epsilon}{\beta}\right) = \left(1 - \frac{w_5}{L} \right)\left(\frac{\epsilon}{\beta}\right) \tag{2b}\label{G2b}$$

---

We really only need to know the tool height error $\epsilon$ to compensate for the misalignment, because the rotation/tilt angle $\theta$ does not affect accuracy at all.

Let's say $d$ is the distance from the tool to the center of the axis, the tool height error is $\epsilon$, and $x$ is the distance from the center of the axis measured along the tool carriage.  Then, because $\epsilon$ and $x$ are perpendicular, Pythagoras tells us
$$d^2 = x^2 + \epsilon^2 \tag{5a}\label{G5a}$$
i.e.
$$x = \sqrt{d^2 - \epsilon^2} \tag{5b}\label{G5b}$$
or equivalently,
$$d = \sqrt{x^2 + \epsilon^2} \tag{5c}\label{G5c}$$

Here, $d$ is the real world distance between the tool tip and the center of the axis, and $x$ is the DRO measurement, with $x = 0$ exactly below the center of the axis and $\epsilon$ the distance between the tool tip and the center of the axis at that point.

Comment: This is amazing, thank you for the help. The angular error does need to be accounted for on the control side because the control believes it's moving the tool along orthagonal axis when in reality it isn't. The math for this correction is straightforward, so all that's left is to implement both. Really, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

With Glarbo's explanation spurring me along I have arrived at what I believe to be the correct solution. The height error varies as a function of the slope of the bed and the wear offset at x=0. This forms a line, y=mx+b. If I substitute this into the equation for a circle where r is the radius that is intended to be cut x^2 + y^2 = r^2, I can simplify and arrive at x=(-mb+sqrt(r^2 + m^2r^2 - b^2)/m^2+1 and x=-((mb+sqrt(r^2+m^2r^2 - b^2))/m^2+1) in general. This gives me intercepts of the line and circle and thus one of these I "should" be cutting at in order to meet the circle. The linear offset is thus r-x. From this linear offset, the "true" offset (distance the x axis needs to move along the sloped line) would be offset=(linear offset)/cos(m). Now all I need to figure out is which x value to ignore. [image: Illustration] The illustration shows in green the offset that is calculated through this method. I am also aware that below a radius value where the tool can intercept the work, this will fail as there are no intercepts. I should be able to use the discriminant described [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-LineIntersection.html) to check for the condition that the tool will not intersect the work and simply disable compensation for those cases.